# How to setup llvm/clang in windows?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to setup an compiler toolchain for cortex-m embedded µController using cmake and clang/llvm.

I downloaded the llvm-project repo from git to a folder and I wanted to get running cmake to be able to compile the toolchain in visual studio, as is discribed [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html). I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Version 16.4.5.

The command in the cmd.exe I type in, is:

```
D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\llvm>cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;lldb;compiler-rt;lld;polly" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/llvmTools" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../llvm -Thost=x64
```

But I get the following failure:

```
D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\llvm>cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-
tools-extra;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;lldb;compiler-rt;lld;polly" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/llvmTools" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../llvm -Thost=x64
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28316.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28316.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- clang project is enabled
-- clang-tools-extra project is enabled
-- compiler-rt project is enabled
-- debuginfo-tests project is disabled
-- libc project is disabled
-- libclc project is disabled
-- libcxx project is enabled
-- libcxxabi project is enabled
-- libunwind project is enabled
-- lld project is enabled
-- lldb project is enabled
-- mlir project is disabled
-- openmp project is disabled
-- parallel-libs project is disabled
-- polly project is enabled
-- pstl project is disabled
-- Could NOT find Z3: Found unsuitable version "0.0.0", but required is at least "4.7.1" (found Z3_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND)
CMake Error at cmake/modules/CheckCompilerVersion.cmake:62 (message):
  Host Visual Studio version 16.4 is known to miscompile part of LLVM, please
  use clang-cl or upgrade to 16.5 or above (use
  -DLLVM_TEMPORARILY_ALLOW_OLD_TOOLCHAIN=ON to ignore)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/config-ix.cmake:13 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:629 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/GitRepos/llvm-project/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/GitRepos/llvm-project/llvm/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

When I open the llvm-project folder directly in Visual Studio, I get an other failure log:

```
CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Command line: "cmd.exe" /c ""C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28316.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28316.0
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe -- works
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe -- works
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] CMake Error at D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang\CMakeLists.txt:66 (find_package):
1> [CMake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
1> [CMake]   the following names:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     LLVMConfig.cmake
1> [CMake]     llvm-config.cmake
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
1> [CMake]   "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
1> [CMake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
1> [CMake]   installed.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "D:/GitRepos/llvm-project/clang/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> [CMake] 
1> cmd.exe /c ""C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang" 2>&1" returned with exit code: 1
```

Can someone tell me, why I get two different failure logs and how to solve them?

Comment: In one command, you are using VS2019 for the generator, but in the second command you are using `Ninja`, which I assume you do not want to do?

Comment: you're correct. In the second one, I just right click on the folder in the windows explorer and click open in visual studio. Everything else is Visual Studio doing by itself, which means, he choose ninja. Ok, I overseen this. But I tried out, and open only the llvm-project/llvm folder in VS and changed the generator to Visual Studio, I get also the same message with "Found unsuitable version...". VS Version 16.4.5 is the most actual version. I updated today to the newest version. I have the newest LLVM version from git. Today downloaded. Is there a bug in llvm??

Comment: You perform the second run using `D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\clang` as a source directory. This is not how llvm should be built. The first run correctly uses `D:\GitRepos\llvm-project` as a source directory (path `../llvm` relative to the current `D:\GitRepos\llvm-project\llvm` directory). Note, that unlike to the documentation which uses **freshly created** `build` subdirectory as a build one, your current directory is `llvm`. This is bad, since this directory is part of the project.